# 502 Caused by protoc >= 3.19.0

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers

```
023-06-25 07:18:17 default[20230625t071600]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app      mod = importlib.import_module(module)    File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed    File "/workspace/main.py", line 4, in <module>      from google.cloud import datastore    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>      from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 24, in <module>      from google.cloud.datastore import helpers    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 31, in <module>      from google.cloud.datastore.key import Key    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/key.py", line 23, in <module>      from google.cloud.datastore import _app_engine_key_pb2    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_app_engine_key_pb2.py", line 36, in <module>      _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 561, in __new__      _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile()  TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
2023-06-25 07:18:17 default[20230625t071600]  If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
```

I did this but still not worked:

The error message you provided indicates that there is an issue with the google.cloud.datastore module and the creation of descriptors. The error message suggests that the generated code is out of date and needs to be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the similar error. Below is what worked for me

`pip install protobuf==3.20.*`